# Using Android Preference classes UI for configuring dynamic data

Tags: android, sqlite, dynamic, preference

For configuring a row of a database table, I'd like to use a UI identical to the Android Preference classes UI. For example, this would be setting a bunch of checkboxes / radios / etc to configure an alarm, in a table that held a number of user-created alarms.

Is it possible and/or appropriate to use the Preference classes for this, rather than manually building my own forms to mimic the UI? I want the UI to look as 'standard' as possible across the range of Android versions.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the row id from the previous activity and set [OnPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) for each preference, and  and every time Preference changes you can update the row.

You could also pass back all values from the preferenceActivity to the calling activity through setResult and update row in OnActivityResult

Comment: Thanks nandeesh - if I understand you're suggesting I'd have a single set of Preferences that would temporarily be over-written to represent the current database row. Before displaying the Preferences, I could set their values to the current table row by accessing SharedPreferences.Editor. This seems like a bit of a hack, using Preferences for something they're not designed to do. Really what I want to do is use the UI of the Preference classes without their built-in back-end logic. Maybe there is no nice way to do this?

Comment: Its kind of a hack, but many apps in the Android source use such approach. So it is a common approach

Comment: Ok that helps - if it's good enough for the Android source, it's good enough for me! Thanks